# I can't call a jQuery, probably because of a syntax error

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, twig

I am using the aBigImage Jquery and while I follow the instructions given, I get an 500 error saying the variable "link" does not exist.
Can you please help me? 
the following code is what I wrote:

```
{% block body %}
<div class="page-sidebar">
    {% for link in entity.getSidebarImages() %}
        {% if link.image.isFoto() %}

            <a href="{{ app.request.basepath }}/{{ link.image.getWebPath() }}">

                <img src="{{ app.request.basepath }}/{{ link.image.getWebPath("thumbnail_250") }}" alt="{{ link.image.title }}">

                <div class="sidebar-description">
                    {{ link.image.description|raw }}
                </div>


            </a>

        {% else %}
            <div class="sidebar-item sidebar-link-item">
                <a href="{{ app.request.basepath }}/{{ link.image.webpath }}">

                 <img src="{{ app.request.basepath }}/{{ link.image.getPreview() }}" />
                </a>
                <div class="sidebar-title">
                    <a href="{{ app.request.basepath }}/{{ link.image.webpath }}">
                      {{ link.image.title|raw }}
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

<script>    
    jQuery('.page-sidebar a').on('click') {
        jQuery(document).ready(function(
        $(  'a[href$="'{{ app.request.basepath }}'/'{{ link.image.getWebPath() }}'"]').abigimage();

    }); 
</script>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block body_javascripts %}
    {% javascripts output='aBigImage.js'
    '@CtrlBlnHomepageBundle/Resources/public/js/Minimal-jQuery-Image-Viewer-with-Image-Preloading-ABigImage/abigimage.jquery.min.js'    
    %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

the error I get is for:

```
$(  'a[href$="'{{ app.request.basepath }}'/'{{ link.image.getWebPath() }}'"]').abigimage();
```

which I think is a syntax mistake but I can't find it... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing *link* variable outside *for* loop.

Comment: You have to remove your _<script>_ tag, and use @DarkBee javascript code instead

Comment: if you would do it some other way what would that be?

Comment: Maybe, `<div class="sidebar-description">` is wrong inside _<a>_ tag

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are creating a secondary selector, switching it up to this should work

```js
$(function() {
 $('.page-sidebar a').abigimage();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.darkbee.be/abigimage.jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="page-sidebar">
   {% for link in entity.getSidebarImages() %}
    {% if link.image.isFoto() %}
     <a href="{{ app.request.basepath }}/{{ link.image.getWebPath() }}">
      <img src="{{ app.request.basepath }}/{{ link.image.getWebPath("thumbnail_250") }}" alt="{{ link.image.title }}">
      <div class="sidebar-description">{{ link.image.description|raw }}</div>
     </a>
    {% else %}
     <div class="sidebar-item sidebar-link-item">
      <a href="{{ app.request.basepath }}/{{ link.image.webpath }}">
       <img src="{{ app.request.basepath }}/{{ link.image.getPreview() }}" />
      </a>
      <div class="sidebar-title">
       <a href="{{ app.request.basepath }}/{{ link.image.webpath }}">
        {{ link.image.title|raw }}
       </a>
      </div>
     </div>
    {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

Comment: i tried it and it seems right but it won't work. i think because the < a href> is inside the for loop